# Return false stops events from happening

Tags: jquery

I have this single page application that instead of pages, loads sections one at a time. The basics of this app is that you input a query and then go a results page, and on top of the results in another form - same as the first form but instead of going to a new view (into a different section of the same page) the results just appear below it. Whenever a new view loads, the other is hidden. (ex: home view has search form. Search, submit, hides home view and then results view).

My problem here is that return false on this line:

```
var actions = $('.action');

actions.on('touchstart click', function(event){
    var $this = $(this);

        if ($this.hasClass('no-view')) {
            doAction($this);
            return false; // here
        } 

    viewHandler($this.attr('href'));
});
```

Is important, but also breaks the click event that is needed here:

```
var tickerResultsInput = $('#PickHolder #ticker');
$('body').on('touchstart click', '#results-submit-ticker', function(e){

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: 'http://www.1dayreturn.com/getPicksdev.php', 
        data: "action=GetEverything&stock="+tickerResultsInput.val()+"&application=android",
        beforeSend: function() {
            pickContent.slideUp('400').html('<h2 class="searchloading">Searching for stock data...</h2>');
            $('#analyze-results-form').show();
        },
        complete: function(data){
            $('.searchloading').hide('300');
            pickContent
                .html(data.responseText)
                .slideDown('400');
        }  
    });
});
```

If you want to take a look at the HTML:

```
<div id="PickHolder" class="view container">
    <form id="analyze-results-form" action="" class="analyze-form">
        <div class="input-container">
            <input id="ticker" class="input-stock" type="text" placeholder="Add Ticker">

        </div><!-- /.input-container -->
        <button id="results-submit-ticker" class="action action-data btn no-view" data-ref="#PickHolder">Analyze</button>
    </form>
    <div id="pick-content"></div>
</div>
```

return false; is important because below the if statement is this: `viewHandler($this.attr('href'));

which is just a function to hide a section and open the requested one:

```
viewHandler = function(ref){
    /*
        ref = value of href or data-ref attr.
        (#home for example)
     */
    var currentView = $('.current'),
        view = $(ref);
    if (ref != currentView.attr('id')) {
        currentView.addClass('animate-exit');
        /*
            When the CSS animation ends
         */
        currentView.one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
            currentView.removeClass("animate-exit current");
            view.addClass('animate-in current');
            /*
                When the new current view CSS animation ends.
             */
            view.one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
                view.removeClass('animate-in');
            });
        });

    } 

}
```

But we don't want this running if the if statement is true, just one the function and then that's it. Not change views.

How can I use return false, or a similar method without breaking the bindings for the click event?

Comment: use event.preventDefault() after doAction($this); line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `return false` will stop event propagation and prevent the default action.

From what I can see, you want only to prevent the default action so

```
var actions = $('.action');

actions.on('touchstart click', function (event) {
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.hasClass('no-view')) {
        doAction($this);
        event.preventDefault();
        return; // here
    }

    viewHandler($this.attr('href'));
});
```

The handlers attached to the body are executed because of the event propogation, since you are stopping it the handler will not be called.